# Nasty symlink issue in snapshot views on Windows

Tags: windows, clearcase

In our company, we're using ClearCase on Windows. Since dynamic views have proven VERY slow for us, we're primarily using snapshot views.

Today we found a really nasty problem regarding symbolic links in snapshot views on Windows.

As we all know, in a snapshot view (at least on Windows) ClearCase models symlinks not via actual file system symlinks but simply as copies. That is, if your original file is **/myVOB/dir/fileA.txt** and **/myVOB/anotherDir/fileA.txt** is a symbolic link to the former, in a snapshot view the former and the latter are simply identical copies of each other. The problem now is that if you checkout and edit the original file (maybe as part of a merge operation), the change is not mirrored in any of the symlinks pointing to that file. Even a view update won't change that ... it will after you've checked-in your changes, but not before, and this is a huge problem because we're using an automated, gated check-in that automatically merges changes from a source branch into a snapshot view, runs the build and any subsequent tests and only proceeds to check-in the changes if the build and all tests were successful.

Due to the above mentioned issue, we've found that it is possible for a gated check-in (i.e. the build and tests) to succeed even though the merged changes should cause it to fail. All it takes for that to happen is the build referencing a changed file or directory not via its true, original path but via a symlink, which will cause it to see the original, unchanged rather than the changed, merged version.

Does anyone have an idea how to work around this problem other than "Just use dynamic views"?

Comment: Have you spent any time troubleshooting the dynamic view issue?

Comment: @BrianCowan What dynamic view issue are you getting at?

Comment: Your dynamic view performance issue. You mentioned that they are "very slow", and there is at least a chance to improve that, assuming that you're not on the other side of the an VPN or other long distance connection from the server.

Comment: @BrianCowan Oh that. Yeah, we've been trying to push our CC administrators / IT department (I'm just a lowly toolsmith) to get to the bottom of that, but so far nowt has come of it.

Comment: apparently SO doesn't have private messages. Not knowing anything about your company, I can't tell you if they have any active performance PMR's, or even if they have a current support contract (decloaking a bit there...). If you can send me your work contact information to my work email (first 2 letters of 1st name + last name _at_ (abbreviation for) United States _dot_ ibm _com_. I can take a look.

Comment: @BrianCowan I appreciate your offer, but I don't really want to dig that deep if I don't have to. I and others have made our IT department and our CC administrators aware of the issue multiple times, but they always blame it on the general network infrastructure, though I find it a bit suspicious that CC performance seems relatively good on UNIX machines and only suffers badly on Windows machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When considering [symbolic link on Windows in ClearCase snapshot views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/c_symlinks_ssv.htm), there does not seem to be any magic solution.

One workaround would be to have a list of those symbolic link (assuming that list is relatively static and does not change often) and, before each build/test, copy the original file (if a `cleartool diff` shows any difference) to those symbolic links referencing it.

[antred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354633/antred) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990276/nasty-symlink-issue-in-snapshot-views-on-windows/35992780#comment60710022_35992780):

> Here's our final solution:
>
> Perform the merge in a DYNAMIC view, do NOT check in.
> Use robocopy to sync the view to a storage location on a hard drive (relatively fast), then run the build / tests from there.
> If it succeeds, check-in changes in dynamic view; else undo checkouts. :)

Comment: Hah, somehow I knew it would be you who writes the first response! :) As for sync'ing the links with the original storage location. We've considered that, but it could get very expensive to crawl through the entire file system and search for links that reference any of the changed elements. Also, simple copies won't always do ... what if the structure of a directory tree has been significantly changed (struff renamed, new files / directories created, old ones removed)?

We're toying with the idea of doing the merge in a dynamic view and then copying everything to a local HD for the build.

Comment: @antred Sure, I was mentioning that workaround only if the symbolic links are known in advance and does not change too often. If not, maybe searching for those symbolic links in a dynamic view, in order to make the relevant copies in the snapshot view.

Comment: Well, I guess we'll have to go with something like that. God, I wish our project wasn't using Windows ...

Comment: I think the "solution" we're going to use for now is perform ANOTHER view update after the merge. That will slow things down a lot, but what use is a fast process if the results are incorrect ...

Comment: @antred OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: You may have to remove it again, because I think I spoke too soon. :-\
If we go back to my original question, we can see that that approach doesn't actually work, because the changes will only be mirrored in the "linked" locations after the changes have actually been checked-in.

Comment: @antred OK, reverted. Please edit this answer if you have more insight.

Comment: Here's our final solution: Perform the merge in a DYNAMIC view, do NOT check in. Use robocopy to sync the view to a storage location on a hard drive (relatively fast), then run the build / tests from there. If it succeeds, check-in changes in dynamic view; else undo checkouts. :)

Comment: @antred Nice! That should work. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.